# How can I display calculated results in a graph when user clicks submit?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I'm using http://canvasjs.com/ to create a bar graph. So far, when the user clicks 'submit' the entered numbers are displayed on a graph http://jsfiddle.net/jx9sJ/5/ .

Now, I'm trying to change it. So the entered numbers are sent to ajax, calculations done, & then encoded using `json_encode($total);` I'm struggling to create the graph from the values, which are in `json_encode`. How can this be done?

Code so far

```
$fortot2 = 5;
$fortot3 = 2;

if (is_numeric($numwelds) && is_numeric($numconwelds))
{
    $total['tot1'] = $numwelds + $numconwelds + $fortot3  ;
    $total['tot2'] = $numwelds + $numconwelds + $fortot2 ;
    $total['tot3'] = $numwelds + $numconwelds; 
    $response = json_encode($total);
    header("Content-Type: application/json");  
    echo $response;
    exit;
}
```

Using print_r  json_encode($total) is structured as

```
  Array ( [tot1] => 3 [tot2] => 5 [tot3] => 1 )
```

Comment: What is the exact question? Are you trying to send an array via AJAX? Do you have trouble creating the graph from the values?

Comment: @Jasper trouble creating the graph from the values, which are in `json_encode`

Comment: Does anyone have any suggestions please? Really stuck with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all,

```
Array ( [tot1] => 3 [tot2] => 5 [tot3] => 1 )
```

is not `json_encode`d and rather looks like `var_dump( $total )`.

Then you have to populate the `data` object that is used on line 15 of your JSFiddle with the values from JSON, which requires some basic knowledge of AJAX. I suggest that you first familiarize yourself with that.